# Google Spreadsheet row update

Tags: google-sheets

I need update a row with function `=importxml()` every 3 minutes to refresh MAP gadget.

I setup function redROWs trigger to every 3 minutes but it doesn't work.
Any idea?

Comment: can you post some code & more details of what you have done. But not sure you will be able to do every 3 mins, there are limits on trigger run time.

Comment: I´m runing this default 
Every  minute from from the trigger wizard.
function function readRows() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var rows = sheet.getDataRange();
  var numRows = rows.getNumRows();
  var values = rows.getValues();

  for (var i = 0; i <= numRows - 1; i++) {
    var row = values[i];
    Logger.log(row);
  }
};

Answer (score 4):

The importXML() is updating every 2 hours by it self and you can't trigger it from a script. Then you have to write the function into your script..

The best solution I found is to add the GoogleClock() to the URL. It makes the ImportXML update every minute automatically. Also when the spreadsheet is not open.

Like this: 
ImportXML("URL"&GoogleClock(),"div...")

Comment: Note: this is "old sheets" behaviour, the new Sheets offering (as of 2014) no longer acts like this, and does not support `GoogleClock()` either.

Answer (score 1):

getActiveSheet() only works when you have the spreadsheet open - use openById

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app#openById(String)

to trigger =importxml , write something to the sheet.