# XPath query to extract current price,volume and average volume in Google Sheets using importxml

Tags: xpath, google-sheets, yahoo-finance, google-sheets-formula

I am trying to import stock real-time price, real-time volume and average volume in Google sheet from Yahoo Finance but not sure about XPath to be used for same.

for example, for URL

https://sg.finance.yahoo.com/quote/AMZN

```
under summary tab:
realtime price: 1910.21
volume: https://sg.finance.yahoo.com/quote/AMZN
avg. volume: 4,406,091
```

here I tried to modify below code but not sure about XPath

```
=INDEX(IMPORTXML("https://sg.finance.yahoo.com/quote/AMZN","//div[@id='quote-header-info']/div[last()]/div[1]"),1)
```

Answer (score 5):

Here are the 3 lines that need.

**Real Time Price**

```
=INDEX(IMPORTXML("https://sg.finance.yahoo.com/quote/AMZN","(//div[@id='quote-header-info']/div[last()]/div[1]//span)[1]"),1)
```

**Volume:**

```
=INDEX(IMPORTXML("https://sg.finance.yahoo.com/quote/AMZN","//td[@data-test='TD_VOLUME-value']/span"),1)
```

**Average:**

```
=INDEX(IMPORTXML("https://sg.finance.yahoo.com/quote/AMZN","//td[@data-test='AVERAGE_VOLUME_3MONTH-value']/span"),1)
```

Comment: tnx a lot, it worked for single record.
But when i am trying to use the same for all NSE F&O stocks, it keeps on loading. Pls. suggest.

Comment: @MGGameLab check with the updated xpath for the real time price. Just changed `/span` to `//span`.

Comment: tnx for reply. still taking same time to load.any idea how to refresh xml import after fixed interval?

Comment: Hope the core xpath issue is fixed (if so please accept the answer). You can refer to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33872967/periodically-refresh-importxml-spreadsheet-function) on refreshing the sheet.