# google sheet importxml to scrape seekingalpha news

Tags: xml, google-sheets, import, google-sheets-formula

I have been using google sheet importxml to scrape seekingalpha for a long time. Recently I find it very difficult to scrape seekingalpha news.

For example to scrape the news from "https://seekingalpha.com/news/3611919-epic-makes-another-attempt-reversing-fortnite-app-store-ban"
I use the below formula:

```
=JOIN(CHAR(13), importxml("https://seekingalpha.com/news/3611919-epic-makes-another-attempt-reversing-fortnite-app-store-ban","//div[@id='bullets_ul']"))
```

Most of the time, it will have the error: could not fetch url.

In the past, I could add "#1234" or other numbers to the url to "force" download again. But such do not seem to work recently.

Any idea to how I can make the news download more reliable?

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for a way to force IMPORTXML to refresh. There does not appear to be a keyboard shortcut for this, so you can either [find an apps-script to do that](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33872967/4294399) for you, or do it this way. (I'm sure there are other ways to do it.)

1. Add a checkbox to some cell (B1 here)
2. Use this:

```
=JOIN(,importxml(REPT(" ",B1)&"https://seekingalpha.com/news/3611919-epic-makes-another-attempt-reversing-fortnite-app-store-ban","//div[@id='bullets_ul']"))
```

By changing the URL, the import will refresh, so when we uncheck or check the box, `REPT` appends 0 or 1 space in front of the URL.

No, we cannot use any function, such as `RAND()` (or any related function) or `NOW()`.