# How to get the current price of a cryptocurrency on google sheets from coinmarketcap?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, cryptocurrency

On a google sheets cell I want to get only the current cryptocurrency price with this formula:

```
=ValueCrypto(A1)
```

I tried this function for coinmarketcap:

```
function ValueCrypto(crypto) {

  var url = "https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/ticker/" + crypto + "/?convert=EUR";
  
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);
  
  var data = JSON.parse(response.getContentText());
  
  return data[0].price_eur;
}
```

the function give me the error "We no longer serving this endpoint here"

I also tried to change the endpoint and I added my apy key into the function:

```
function ValueCrypto(crypto) {

  var url = "pro-api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/cryptocurrency/quotes/latest?symbol=" + crypto
  var requestOptions = {
  method: 'GET',
  uri: 'https://pro-api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/cryptocurrency/listings/latest',
  qs: {
    start: 1,
    limit: 5000,
    convert: 'EUR'
  },
  headers: {
    'X-CMC_PRO_API_KEY': 'myapikey'
  },
  json: true,
  gzip: true
};

  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);
  
  var data = JSON.parse(response.getContentText());

  return data[0].price_eur;
}
```

and the errors now are:
Exception: Request failed for http://pro-api.coinmarketcap.com returned code 401. Truncated server response: {
"status": {
"timestamp": "2021-01-02T11:31:39.880Z",
"error_code": 1002,
"error_message": "API key missing.",
... (use muteHttpExceptions option to examine full response)

Comment: Which do you want to use `pro-api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/cryptocurrency/quotes/latest` or `https://pro-api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/cryptocurrency/listings/latest`? I couldn't understand about your goal from your question. I apologize for this.

Answer (score 3):

I found that the accepted answer isn't properly formated as per the latest API docs. Heres my solution which seems to work well for me (Be sure to place the API key and quote currency):

```html
function ValueCrypto(crypto = "BTC") {
    var url = "https://pro-api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/cryptocurrency/quotes/latest?symbol=" + crypto;
    var requestOptions = {
        method: 'GET',
        uri: 'https://pro-api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/cryptocurrency/quotes/latest?symbol=',
        qs: {
            start: 1,
            limit: 5000,
            convert: 'USD'
        },
        headers: {
            'X-CMC_PRO_API_KEY': 'INSERT_KEY_HERE'
        },
        json: true,
        gzip: true
    };
    var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, requestOptions);
    var data = JSON.parse(response.getContentText());
    //console.log(data.data[crypto].quote.USD.price);
    return data.data[crypto].quote.USD.price;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code does not appear to use `requestOptions` which is where the API key is defined. Try passing it to `UrlFetchApp` like this:

```
var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, requestOptions);
```

See documentation for [UriFetchApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app#fetchurl,-params).

Comment: Thanks for your reply, now the error is Exception: Request failed for http://pro-api.coinmarketcap.com returned code 400. Truncated server response: {"status":{"timestamp":"2021-01-02T11:51:40.775Z","error_code":400,"error_message":"Invalid value for \"symbol\": \"UNDEFINED\"","elapsed":0,"credi... (use muteHttpExceptions option to examine full response)

Comment: Are you setting `crypto` which is referenced in `url` to a valid symbol? Or is the symbol supposed to be added as a parameter in `qs: {}`? And what should `uri` be set to?

Comment: I want to pass the crypto through cell: =ValueCrypto(A1)

Comment: function ValueCrypto(crypto) {

  var url = "https://pro-api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/cryptocurrency/quotes/latest?symbol=" + crypto;

  var requestOptions = {
  method: 'GET',
  uri: 'https://pro-api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/cryptocurrency/quotes/latest?symbol=',
  qs: {
    start: 1,
    limit: 5000,
    convert: 'EUR'
  },
  headers: {
    'X-CMC_PRO_API_KEY': ''
  },
  json: true,
  gzip: true
};

  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, requestOptions);
  
  var data = JSON.parse(response.getContentText());

  return data[0].price_eur;
}

Comment: Set `url='https://pro-api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/cryptocurrency/quotes/latest'`. Also remove `start` and `limit`. Add `symbol: 'BTC'` to `qs` options dict.

Comment: sorry this solution not works:
function ValueCrypto(crypto) {

  var url='https://pro-api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/cryptocurrency/quotes/latest';

  var requestOptions = {
  method: 'GET',
  uri: 'https://pro-api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/cryptocurrency/quotes/latest',
  qs: {
    symbol : 'BTC',
    convert: 'EUR'
  },
  headers: {
    'X-CMC_PRO_API_KEY': 'myapikey'
  },
  json: true,
  gzip: true
};

  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, requestOptions);
  
  var data = JSON.parse(response.getContentText());

  return data[0].price_eur;
}

Comment: the error is: Exception: Request failed for https://pro-api.coinmarketcap.com returned code 400. Truncated server response: {"status":{"timestamp":"2021-01-02T15:00:35.973Z","error_code":400,"error_message":"\"value\" must contain at least one of [id, symbol, slug]","ela... (use muteHttpExceptions option to examine full response)

Answer (score 0):

#### Modification points:

- When I saw the official document of [Quick Start Guide](https://coinmarketcap.com/api/documentation/v1/#section/Quick-Start-Guide) of CoinMarketCap API, as the sample curl command, I found the following sample curl command.

  ```
    curl -H "X-CMC_PRO_API_KEY: b54bcf4d-1bca-4e8e-9a24-22ff2c3d462c" -H "Accept: application/json" -d "start=1&limit=5000&convert=USD" -G https://pro-api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/cryptocurrency/listings/latest
  ```
- In this case, the data of `start=1&limit=5000&convert=USD` is required to be used as the query parameter.
- When I saw your script, it seems that the values of `symbol, start, limit, convert` are used. In this case, please use the values like `symbol=${crypto}&start=1&limit=5000&convert=EUR`. And, `headers: {'X-CMC_PRO_API_KEY': 'myapikey'}` can be used at `params` of `fetch(url, params)`.
- It seems that the URL is `https://###`.

When above points are reflected to your script, it becomes as follows.

#### Modified script:

Before you use this, please set `'X-CMC_PRO_API_KEY': 'myapikey'` using your API key.

```
function ValueCrypto(crypto) {
  // This is from https://gist.github.com/tanaikech/70503e0ea6998083fcb05c6d2a857107
  String.prototype.addQuery = function(obj) {
    return this + Object.keys(obj).reduce(function(p, e, i) {
      return p + (i == 0 ? "?" : "&") +
        (Array.isArray(obj[e]) ? obj[e].reduce(function(str, f, j) {
          return str + e + "=" + encodeURIComponent(f) + (j != obj[e].length - 1 ? "&" : "")
        },"") : e + "=" + encodeURIComponent(obj[e]));
    },"");
  }

  var url = "https://pro-api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/cryptocurrency/listings/latest"; // or var url = "https://pro-api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/cryptocurrency/quotes/latest";
  var query = {
    symbol: crypto,
    start: 1,
    limit: 5000,
    convert: 'EUR'
  };
  var endpoint = url.addQuery(query); // <--- https://pro-api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/cryptocurrency/listings/latest?symbol=###&start=1&limit=5000&convert=EUR

  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(endpoint, {headers: {'X-CMC_PRO_API_KEY': 'myapikey', 'Accept': 'application/json'}});
  return response.getContentText();
}
```

- In this modified script, Listings Latest is used. When you want to use Quotes Latest, please modify the URL to `var url = "https://pro-api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/cryptocurrency/quotes/latest";`.

#### Note:

- From the official document, I thought that `data[0].price_eur` might be `undefined`. Because `data[0].price_eur` is usef for `api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/ticker`. So in this sample script, I returned `response.getContentText()`. When you put `=ValueCrypto(A1)` to a cell, the returned value can be seen. From this value, can you show the sample result value and the output value you want? By this, I would like to modify it.
- When your API key is invalid, an error occurs. Please be careful this.

#### References:

- [Quick Start Guide](https://coinmarketcap.com/api/documentation/v1/#section/Quick-Start-Guide)
- [Listings Latest](https://coinmarketcap.com/api/documentation/v1/#operation/getV1CryptocurrencyListingsLatest)
- [Quotes Latest](https://coinmarketcap.com/api/documentation/v1/#operation/getV1CryptocurrencyQuotesLatest)
- [UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, params)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app#fetchurl,-params)

Comment: sorry but still error: Exception: Request failed for https://pro-api.coinmarketcap.com returned code 400. Truncated server response: {"status":{"timestamp":"2021-01-03T19:50:46.417Z","error_code":400,"error_message":"\"symbol\" is not allowed","elapsed":0,"credit_count":0}} (use muteHttpExceptions option to examine full response)

Comment: @romoleta Thank you for replying. I apologize for the inconvenience. From your error message of `\"symbol\" is not allowed`, it is found that the authorization error was removed. But, it seems that your `crypto` of symbol: crypto` is invalid. In this case, this modified script might not be related to this error. Unfortunately, from your replying, I cannot understand about the value of `crypto`. I apologize for this. So can you confirm the value of `crypto` you gave again? By the way, I cannot still understand which you want to use "Listings Latest" or "Quotes Latest". How about this?

Comment: I tried both "Listings Latest" and "Quotes Latest", I would like that crypto is a variable, so for example I can write symbols on google sheets column A, and get the current prices on column B through the formula =ValueCrypto(A1)

Comment: @romoleta Thank you for replying. About `I would like that crypto is a variable`, my modified script uses `crypto` as the variable. So when `=ValueCrypto(A1)` is put to a cell, the value of "A1" is used as the value of `crypto`. But from your replying, I couldn't understand about the value of the cell "A1"? I apologize for this. So, can I ask you about the value of the cell "A1"? Because your current error message is `\"symbol\" is not allowed`. And, can you provide your current script for replicating your issue? By this, I would like to try to understand about it.

Comment: A1 is empty because the error occurs when I click run on appscript editor, so A1 is not full, I think that the variable crypto needs immediately a temporary symbol as value

Comment: @romoleta Thank you for replying. I apologize for the inconvenience. From `=ValueCrypto(A1)`, I had thought that you wanted to use the script as the custom function. But from `A1 is empty because the error occurs when I click run on appscript editor, so A1 is not full, I think that the variable crypto needs immediately a temporary symbol as value`, I understood that in your case, you had wanted to run the script with the script editor. I deeply apologize for my poor English skill.

Comment: @romoleta In order to directly run the script with the script editor, it is required to declare `crypto`. For this, please set it and test it again. If you cannot understand about my replying, as a sample value, please add `crypto = crypto || "BTC";` after the line of `function ValueCrypto(crypto) {` and test it again. In this case, `crypto` is not given, `BTC` is used as the value.

Comment: Thank you for your help @Tanaike, cmc has a very terrible api and the error still Exception: Request failed for https://pro-api.coinmarketcap.com returned code 400. Truncated server response: {"status":{"timestamp":"2021-01-05T18:25:50.538Z","error_code":400,"error_message":"\"start\" is not allowed","elapsed":0,"credit_count":0}} (use muteHttpExceptions option to examine full response)

Comment: @romoleta Thank you for replying. I apologize for the inconvenience. From your replying, it was found that the error of `\"symbol\" is not allowed` was removed. About your new issue of `\"start\" is not allowed`, I think that this is the same with the previous one. So can you confirm about the value of `start`? `start` seems 1 as the default value from the official document. In this case, I think that your this issue is also not related to the script. So I would like to recommend to tell your this issue to the manager of the API.

Answer (score 0):

These work for me

```
  function fetchAll() {
  const apiKey = 'xxxxxxx-xxxxxxx-xxxxxxx-xxxxxxx-xxx'
  fetchCoin({ crypto: "SAFEMOON", fiat: "CAD", firstCell: "B9", apiKey })
  fetchCoin({ crypto: "SAFEMOON", fiat: "USD", firstCell: "B8", apiKey })

}

function fetchCoin({ crypto, fiat, firstCell, apiKey }) {
      const ascii = firstCell[0].toLowerCase().charCodeAt(0)
  try {
    var options = {
      headers: { 'X-CMC_PRO_API_KEY': apiKey }
    }
    var url = `https://pro-api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/cryptocurrency/quotes/latest?symbol=${crypto}&convert=${fiat}`
    var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);
    var res = JSON.parse(response);
    SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getRange(`${String.fromCharCode(ascii - 1)}${firstCell[1]}`).setValue(fiat)
    SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getRange(`${String.fromCharCode(ascii + 0)}${firstCell[1]}`).setValue(res.data[crypto].quote[fiat].price)
    SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getRange(`${String.fromCharCode(ascii + 1)}${firstCell[1]}`).setValue(res.data[crypto].quote[fiat].percent_change_1h)
    SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getRange(`${String.fromCharCode(ascii + 2)}${firstCell[1]}`).setValue(res.data[crypto].quote[fiat].percent_change_24h)
    SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getRange(`${String.fromCharCode(ascii + 3)}${firstCell[1]}`).setValue(res.data[crypto].quote[fiat].percent_change_7d)
    SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getRange(`${String.fromCharCode(ascii + 4)}${firstCell[1]}`).setValue(res.data[crypto].quote[fiat].percent_change_30d)
    SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getRange(`${String.fromCharCode(ascii + 5)}${firstCell[1]}`).setValue(Utilities.formatDate(new Date(res.data[crypto].quote[fiat].last_updated), 'America/New_York', 'MMMM dd, yyyy HH:mm:ss Z'))


    Logger.log({ url, ascii,res })
  } catch (e) {
        SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getRange(`${String.fromCharCode(ascii - 1)}${firstCell[1]}`).setValue("")
    SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getRange(`${String.fromCharCode(ascii + 0)}${firstCell[1]}`).setValue(`Something is broke... ${e.message}`)
    SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getRange(`${String.fromCharCode(ascii + 1)}${firstCell[1]}`).setValue("")
    SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getRange(`${String.fromCharCode(ascii + 2)}${firstCell[1]}`).setValue("")
    SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getRange(`${String.fromCharCode(ascii + 3)}${firstCell[1]}`).setValue("")
    SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getRange(`${String.fromCharCode(ascii + 4)}${firstCell[1]}`).setValue("")
    SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getRange(`${String.fromCharCode(ascii + 5)}${firstCell[1]}`).setValue("")
  }
}
```

Comment: Please explain what your code does and how it does it.

Answer (score 0):

You can skip the API and use this formula in the cell where you want the price:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(IMPORTXML(CONCATENATE("https://coinmarketcap.com/currencies/",CELL("contents",A2),"?update="),"//div[contains(@class, 'priceTitle')]"), 1, 1), INDEX(IMPORTXML(CONCATENATE("https://www.coingecko.com/en/coins/",CELL("contents",A2),"?update="),"//span[@data-coin-symbol]//text()"), 1, 1))
```

Cell A2 would contain 'bitcoin' or some other crypto slug. The formula uses coinmarketcap as it's primary source, and coingecko as a backup source. If you want it to auto-refresh, you can look here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44170267/10642485