# How to add live view count from Instagram into Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, instagram

I am currently using a Google Sheet to keep track of viewer count on several Instagram videos. My current formula:

=REGEXEXTRACT(IMPORTXML("A1","//script[@type='application/ld+json']"),"userInteractionCount"":""(\d+)")

(A1 is actually the instagram page link)
It grabs the viewer count that I need , but it doesn't seem to auto-update when I refresh the page or when I close and reopen the page. Only way for the number to update is deleting are re-entering the formula. As I will be eventually keeping tabs on almost 1,000 videos, I would love a solution on how it updates with a page refresh or when I re-open the page.

Answer (score 0):

#### Solution:

In order to make sure the imported data updates periodically, you can set up an Apps Script [time-driven trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#time-driven_triggers) that will periodically execute a function (called `myFunction` in the example below) that will:

- Retrieve the formula, using [Range.getFormula()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getformula)
- Clear the cell, using [Range.clearContent()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#clearcontent).
- Set the formula again, using [Range.setFormula(formula)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setformulaformula).

#### Workflow:

- Click `Tools > Script editor` in order to open the script editor.
- Install the time-driven trigger. You can do that manually, following [these steps](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#managing_triggers_manually), or programmatically, by copying this function to the script editor and executing it once:

```
function createTrigger() {
  ScriptApp.newTrigger("myFunction")
  .timeBased()
  .everyMinutes(1) // Alternatively, set it to 5,10,15,30 or use .everyHours
  .create()
}
```

> **Note**: In this example, the function is set to run every minute; you can change that period by setting another value at `.everyMinutes(1)` -1, 5, 10, 15, 30 are allowed, see [everyMinutes(n)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/script/clock-trigger-builder#everyMinutes(Integer))- or using [everyHours(n)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/script/clock-trigger-builder#everyhoursn) instead, that's up to you.

- Once the trigger is installed, a function called `myFunction` will run with the periodicity you have previously set. For example, if the formula is in cell `A2` from `Sheet1`:

```
function myFunction() {
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  const cell = sheet.getRange("A2");
  const formula = cell.getFormula();
  cell.clearContent();
  SpreadsheetApp.flush();
  cell.setFormula(formula);
}
```

#### Related:

- [Periodically refresh IMPORTXML() spreadsheet function](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33872967)